# .replace() not working in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm having trouble getting the replace function to work. Here's my code:

```
var divid = $(this).parents(".list-radio").attr('id').match(/\d/g);
divid = divid.replace(/\,/g,"");
```

The first line brings back a set of digits separated by commas (e.g. "2,2,3") and I was hoping the second line would remove the commas, but it just fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Ash

Comment: why are you escaping the , ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `.match` gives you an array of digits, without commas. If you `alert` the array or try to turn it into a text representation by some other means, it may show up as a comma spearated list, but that's just a presentational artefact.

If you want the result as a string of digits without commas you may run `divid.join('')`. Another way would be to just remove anything that isn't a digit from the original string:

```
var divid = $(this).parents(".list-radio").attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'');
```